# Не знаю как поменять имя с кириллицы

Tags: python, django, pip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите, из-за имени на кириллице не могу установить pyinstaller и запустить локальный сервер на Django. Хочу поменять имя с кириллицы на латиницу, но не знаю как. Начал погружаться в программирование, (14 лет) застрял на этом этапе, не могу ничего сделать из за имени на кириллице. Нужна помощь. Постоянно вылезают ошибки одна за другой при исполнении кода.

Comment: Поменяйте имя пользователя на английское в настройках Windows, должно помочь.
Достаточно ввести "windows изменить имя пользователя" и выбрать нужную вам версию, там распишут как

Comment: @RecursiveDaun неа, этого мало, надо будет ещё профиль переименовывать.

Comment: @RecursiveDaun, не поможет - изменение имени пользователя не меняет имя папки пользователя.